# Multiline button in Xamarin? &#x0a; is not working

Tags: xaml, xamarin, button

Using `&#x0a;` is not working. Instead my button only appears to say "First Line."

```
<Button Text="First Line&#x0a;Second Line"/>
```

Am I doing this incorrectly? Is there another simple way to make the text go onto the second line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I test it on Android,it works well,Did you run on ios ? I think this is mainly a problem with iOS because Android will wrap the text by default.

If you want run on ios,you could use customrenderer to achieve this.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Button), typeof(iosbutton))]
namespace EntryCa.iOS
{
  class iosbutton :ButtonRenderer
  {

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.TitleLabel.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
            Control.TitleLabel.Lines = 0;
            Control.TitleLabel.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, Android wraps text by default. Sorry, I am new to Xamarin-- what type of file should this be put into? An empty c# file under the iOS folder?

Comment: @11thal11thal You could create a class in ios project.Refer to [CustomRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/introduction)